# Storing stylesheets for a website in MVC architecture

Tags: css, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I am building up a website using MVC architecture. It takes a lot of css with it. I require atleast 20 css files to store within it each associated with some unique views. I want to know  where can I store the css files? Either in a single root css directory or shall I store it with a particular view. Also linking these files within the common template file would be tedious enough. I mean it would show up 20 different  tags. Is there any alternative way to do this? Please help. I am using codeigniter framework by the way.

Comment: May i ask why are you splitting css in 20 different files?

Answer (score 1):

What I do is store it all in a css folder inside the public folder (the one that houses your index.php file). I also have a helper method that generates the actual link tags, so in the template files, I just have something like:

```
<?= stylesheet('sheet1','sheet2','sheet3') ?>
```

The helper method that calls would then make the links (and assumes that they're in the public/css directory).

That cleans up the raw template files, though it does still make multiple tags in the files themselves. I use partial views, so there's a master view that has the main CSS file(s) that are used on every page (or almost every page), then add in on each template the ones that are unique to the view.

If you have 20 CSS files, you might want to go through and see what you can tidy up and make more generic. Any place where you have more than one of the same styles (even across files) is up for the chopping block. Any extra files should be relatively small and provide only overrides for the exception pages (and if you can genericize those more, so you use a file for more than one page, then that's even better).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to combine all the CSS files in a single file. Its easier to maintain and you will have only one request to the server. Having so many css files will only increase the loading time of your page. Also gzip the css files to increase the page speed.